# PHPStorm 8 port editing

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp, phpstorm, slim

Win8+WAMP Server+PHPStorm8. I've created an app using Slim microframework. 
code:

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

$app->run();
```

And there's no possible way to open it in PHPStorm for testing.

[image: PHPStorm error]

But when I tried to open my project from the folder it works correctly

[image]

It looks like it's caused by port after `localhost`.
I think it's default PHPStorm port `:63342`.
But how can I remove this port? Do I need to change my `hosts` file in OS or my .htaccess in the project?

Comment: IDE uses such links (internal simple web server) when you did not specify any Deployment entries. Just define one (it could be just "Local" where no files will be copied anywhere) and mark it as Default for this project. Obviously, do not forget to specify your base URL there. Now IDE will use that URL when you use "Open in Bowser" functionality.

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm

Comment: sorry but can you explain how to define this as a question. I sure to give you 'Right answer' mark.

Comment: You already asked a question. This whole page is a question and I'm writing comments to your question. In any case: does it mean that you have solved your problem (following my advice)?

Comment: @LazyOne As the answer* 
How can I define a Deplyment entry?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you are asking here. Are you asking how to define Deployment entry? If yes -- did you follow the links I gave you (1st one in particular)? In any case: `Setting (Preferences on Mac) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`